# How to search within Sphinx results using partial words?

Tags: yii, sphinx

I have a form and when I enter a value, I want to get the results on submit;

If I search for `fish` and I have a `fishing` value I want to get all the data that contain the `fish` value;

In my code, I get the results that I need only if I enter the full `fishing` word;

I am searching for the full expression and also for each word from the expression;

```
$sphinx_search = Yii::app()->search;
        $sphinx_search->setSelect('*');

        $sphinx_search_final = '';

        $sphinx_search_query = trim($this->q);
        if (strlen($sphinx_search_query) > 0) {
            $sphinx_search_query = str_replace('-', ' ', $sphinx_search_query);
            $keys = explode(' ', $sphinx_search_query);
            foreach ($keys as $k => $key) {
                if ($key) {
                    $keys[$k] = $key;
                } else {
                    unset($keys[$k]);
                }
            }
            if (count($keys) > 0) {
                $sphinx_search_final = ' @(position_name,employer_name,employer_first_name,employer_last_name,employer_position) ' . $sphinx_search_query .
                        ' @(position_name,employer_name,employer_first_name,employer_last_name,employer_position) ' . implode('|', $keys);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I am searching for the full expression and also for each word from the expression;" - Why? It if matches the first expression, then it matches the second. and if it doesnt match the first, and does the second, it still wont show, as it needs to match both. extra compliexity is pointless. It serves no purpose as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either enable [`min_prefix_len`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len) or [`min_infix_len`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len)
to get explicit substring matching capablities.

Do also check [`enable_star`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-enable-star) as that changes how exactly it behaves.

---

Alternativly maybe stemming is what you looking for? Enabled via [`morphology`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology)